# rails 5.1.4 with vue and webpacker, compilation failed error on deploy

Tags: vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5, vue-component, digital-ocean, webpacker

I have a problem deploying a simple rails app with webpacker and vue to a digitalocean droplet.

As soon as i add the moment dependency to a vue component the compilation process on the server fails. (without output) I'm at a loss on how to find a solution.

the way i add a dependency in main.js:

```
import moment from 'moment';
Vue.prototype.$moment = moment
```

and how I use it in the component:

```
this.score.day = this.$moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Output on the server for 'RAILS_ENV=production bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace'

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.1.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.85s.
** Execute assets:precompile
** Invoke webpacker:compile (first_time)
** Invoke webpacker:verify_install (first_time)
** Invoke webpacker:check_node (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_node
** Invoke webpacker:check_yarn (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_yarn
** Invoke webpacker:check_binstubs (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:check_binstubs
** Execute webpacker:verify_install
Webpacker is installed  
Using /var/www/beleep-2/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
** Invoke environment 
** Execute webpacker:compile
Compiling…
Compilation failed:
```

Other methods of adding the dependency in the component result in the same problem. Everything works perfectly in development mode on my laptop. Hope any of you can point me in the right direction to fixing this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was solved by precompiling on my dev laptop. see for more information: [this github issue](http://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/955#issuecomment-336860736)

Comment: thank you. you just answered a question i was trying to figure out for hours.